# How about MC68HC05, HC11 series compared to MCS-51 chips?

Tags: embedded

How about MC68HC05, HC11 series compared to MCS-51 chips?

1. As a 51 user, is it any benefit to give 68xx a try?
2. Is the community of 68xx larger and more active than 51?
3. I feel that 51's accumulator is too heavy used, if there's two accumulators, many things will be gracefully simplified. How about 68xx?
4. Compare the two's power consumption?
5. In architecture perspective, which is better?
6. Which is more convenient for development?
7. Which is more RISC-style?

Comment: Can you flesh out your question ? WRT what are you comparing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

I have prorgrammed the MC68HC05 in assembler some 15 years ago and found it to be very simple and the instructionset and addressing modes are lovely. The 68HC05 has one accumulator and it's an 8-bit processor (with a 16 bit program counter), it's not a RISC-architecture but I think the instruction-set is somewhat RISC-like (Compered to the intel x86 processors) anyway ... very clean stuff to work with.

Comment: So, I'd like to have a try if it's really as clean as you said.

Comment: Here's a free simulator http://webspace.webring.com/people/ju/um_2949/